# Apply if only on one column on result

Tags: sql, sql-server

This are sample template

```
UserDetails : id,UserName,IsShow
Brand       : id,BrandName
Product     : id,ProductName
BrandProduct:id,brandid,productid,price
```

If Isshow is false, show entire price else hide second -fourth digit.(Price is 5 digits)

Query :

```
create procedure Sp_Details
@brandid int,
@productid int,
@IsShow bit
as
begin
        select B.Brandname,P.Producetname,Bp.Price
        from BrandProduct Bp
        inner join B
        on Bp.brandid = B.id
        inner join P
        on Bp.productid = P.id
        where brandid = @brandid
        and productid = @productid 
end
```

I don't want to use case, isnull or any user created functions because that works row by row. Here @Isshow is either false or true, not specific to each record, it is the same for all records.

Apart from dynamic sql or writing same query twice with if else.. is there any other way to achieve where don't have to write same query twice? Because a few queries are bigger in size.

```
If(@Isshow = false)
begin
     select B.Brandname,P.Producetname,Bp.Price
        from BrandProduct Bp
        inner join B
        on Bp.brandid = B.id
        inner join P
        on Bp.productid = P.id
        where brandid = @brandid
        and productid = @productid 
end
else
begin
      select B.Brandname,P.Producetname, REPLACE(Price, (SUBSTRING(Price,2, 3)), 'xxx')
        from BrandProduct Bp
        inner join B
        on Bp.brandid = B.id
        inner join P
        on Bp.productid = P.id
        where brandid = @brandid
        and productid = @productid 
end
```

Comment: this should be handle in your front end application

Comment: I assume the `Price` column is numeric right ? Do note that In your first query of the `IF ELSE` , you are returning a numeric data type to the front end. In the second, you are actually returning a string and not numeric

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select
    B.Brandname,
    P.Producetname,
    REPLACE(Price, (SUBSTRING(Price,2, 3*@Isshow)), 'xxx')
from
    BrandProduct Bp
    inner join B on Bp.brandid = B.id
    inner join P on Bp.productid = P.id
where
    brandid = @brandid
    and productid = @productid
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually use CASE WHEN statement to do this

```
SELECT B.Brandname,
       P.Producetname,
       CASE
            WHEN @Isshow = 0 THEN CAST(Bp.Price AS VARCHAR(MAX))
            WHEN @Isshow = 1 THEN REPLACE(Bp.Price, (SUBSTRING(Bp.Price,2, 3)), 'xxx')
       END AS [Price]
FROM BrandProduct Bp
INNER JOIN B
ON Bp.brandid = B.id
INNER JOIN P
ON Bp.productid = P.id
WHERE brandid = @brandid
AND productid = @productid
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Squirrel suggested, this should be handled within your presentation layer/front end application.

---

That aside, instead of using `replace` *and* `substring` you can just use `stuff` to achieve this inside a `case` expression:

```
declare @price int = 12345;
declare @show bit = 0;

select @price as Show
      ,stuff(@price,2,3,'xxx') as NoShow

      ,case when @show = 1
            then cast(@price as varchar(5))
            else stuff(@price,2,3,'xxx')
            end as ConditionalShow
;
```

Output:

```
+---------+----------+-------------------+
|  Show   |  NoShow  |  ConditionalShow  |
+---------+----------+-------------------+
|  12345  |  1xxx5   |  1xxx5            |
+---------+----------+-------------------+
```

Working example: http://rextester.com/ASPBV49833